# Solving a 2x2 matrix ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am able to solve ordinary differential systems of the form

> Find the solution of the ODE 
>   $$\frac{dX}{dt} = AX$$
>   where $X$ is a $2\times1$ matrix and $A$ is $2\times2$

However I am not able to find a solution where $X$ is $2\times2$

Can somebody please provide me hint on how to approach such a problem?

Take $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-2\\
-2 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Edit:

Write $U=P^{-1}X$ to obtain $U'=DU$
Thus 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1' &x_2'\\
x_3' &x_4'\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 &0\\
0 &3\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 &x_2\\
x_3 &x_4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
This gives us

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1' &x_2'\\
x_3' &x_4'\\
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
-x_1 &-x_2\\
3x_3 &3x_4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
which gives us 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 &x_2\\
x_3 &x_4\\
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-t} &e^{-t}\\
e^{3t} &e^{3t}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Plugging it in $X=PU$ gives us 
$$X =\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1\\
-1 &1\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
e^{-t} &e^{-t}\\
e^{3t} &e^{3t}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix solution to  $$\frac{dX}{dt} = AX$$

is the exponential $$ X= e^{tA}$$

where

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-2\\
-2 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

There are different methods to find  $ e^{tA} $

One way is to find two linearly independent vectors satisfying your   $$ \frac{dV}{dt} = AV$$ with initial values of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$

These vectors are then the columns of your matrix solution $X=e^{tA}$.

Comment: But how will the answer be expressed?

Comment: As a two by two matrix which satisfies your differential equation.

Comment: Can you show me a source which solves an example so I can familiarise myself with the method or solve a similar question?

Comment: Sure, the differential equation book by Polking,Bogges, Arnold, Second edition. ( Pearson )

Comment: I think I got it. Is the answer $A = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{-t}+e^{3t} &e^{-t}+e^{3t}\\
e^{-t}-e^{3t} &e^{-t}-e^{3t}\\
\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: I have posted the solution on the edit. Can you please see what is the problem?

Comment: Do I need any arbitrary constants to generalize the solution if yes then how should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Write $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal, and set $U=P^{-1}X$. Then
$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = P^{-1} \frac{dX}{dt} = P^{-1}AX = P^{-1}PDP^{-1}X = DU
$$
which is easy to solve. Then $X=PU$.

Comment: Okay but then what is x?

Comment: @mathisbetter, $X=PU$.

Comment: And what's u? As in what is dimensions?

Comment: I think I got it. Is the answer $A = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{-t}+e^{3t} &e^{-t}+e^{3t}\\
e^{-t}-e^{3t} &e^{-t}-e^{3t}\\
\end{pmatrix}$?